# Regex to match only specific parameters in URLs

Tags: regex

I want to match specific parameters in URLs. Following are the regex variants I've tried and they do the job but not completely. Any solutions?

URL parameters-

```
http://www.test.com/test/link/?a=123
http://www.test.com/test/link.xyz/?a=123
http://www.test.com/test/?a=123.123
http://www.test.com/test/test/?a=123
http://www.test.com/test.abc.123
http://www.test.com/test.abc
http://www.test.com/test
```

I am looking to get last three parameters and ignore the rest. So far I've tried below regex, which gets all parameters.

```
.*\/\b(.*[A-Za-z0-9])$
```

This regex gets only last two parameters;

```
.*\/\b(.*[A-Za-z])$
```

How to get only last three parameters and ignore the rest, so that the output is only;

```
test.abc.123
test.abc
test
```

Comment: What are your selection criteria in general description?  The examples may not be enough to infer what you want.

Comment: I do not understand your question. At least give more examples, what should be the output for a specific input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat matching word characters optionally separated by a dot in group 1, and match the forward slash before it.

```
\/([A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*)$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qTN1Fn/1)

The group 1 value per match will be:

```
test.abc.123
test.abc
test
```